# Как добавить иконку на кнопку, как по обтравочной маске в Photoshop?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в макете есть кнопка [image: кнопка]

В нее добавлена иконка в SVG, но добавлена по обтравочной маске, т.е. края иконки обрезаются по контуру кнопки, но сама иконка остается целой (просто скрытой).

https://www.flaticon.com/free-icon/female_766514#term=female&page=1&position=7

Как такое реализовать при верстке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для кнопки добавляются свойства `overflow: hidden;` и `position: relative`, для внутреннего элемента в кнопке (:before или :after подходят лучше всего) добавляется свойство `position: absolute;`. Теперь можно двигать иконку, размещенную во внутреннем свойствами `left`, `top`, `bottom` и `right`. При этом у кнопки будет присутствовать обтравка.

Пример:

```css
.btn {
  background: #555;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 30px;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #222;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.btn:before {
  content: "♀";
  /*background: url('ссылка_на_svg'); /* Вместо content
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px; /* Размеры иконки */
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -15px;
  left: -5px;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">Кнопка</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось.